# What does 'as it was' meaning?

Tags: american-english, british-english

What does it mean if someone says..."**as it was**", in a sentence like

"I won't have enough time to stop and then get to the office, as it was I only managed about 10 minutes there which clearly isn't enough time to do it justice"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "as it was" in context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114325/meaning-of-as-it-was-in-context)

Comment: https://www.englishforums.com/English/ThePhraseAsItWas/xdpgx/post.htm

Comment: Consider 'We didn't have enough supplies to stay in the advance camp for over a week. As it was, we were almost out of water when we made it back to base.' There is _often_ a sense that, though some mitigating factor (here, getting back to base camp) has softened / avoided a blow, the result was still pretty (here) to very unpleasant. // This _need_ not be the interpretation: 'We were outplayed for most of the match, but as it was, we won!' But again, a contrast between what was expected and what actually transpired.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you. Could you please clarify a little better? I'm learning English

Comment: 'We didn't have enough supplies to stay in the advance camp for over a week. _As it was_, we were almost out of water when we made it back to base.' = 'We didn't have enough supplies to stay in the advance camp for over a week. We started back to base camp after a week, _but even so_, we were almost out of water when we made it back to base.' (ie the sense that things were not good as it was/transpired, but could/would have been so much worse given less favourable occurrences/decisions). // There can be other contrasts, though: 'We thought we'd enough milk for 5 days, but as it was/turned out,

Comment: ... what we had lasted 7 / only lasted 3.'

Answer (score -1):

*"I won't have enough time to stop and then get to the office, as it was I only managed about 10 minutes there which clearly isn't enough time to do it justice"?*

Probably better punctuated as:

*"**I won't have enough time to stop and then get to the office, as it was, I only managed about 10 minutes there, which clearly isn't enough time to do it justice"?***

This is saying, I assume, in response to a question like: "Next time you go to the office, can you stop at my home first?:

"I won't have enough time to stop [at your home] and then continue to the office, [BECAUSE the last time I made the journey]  *I only managed about 10 minutes there [at the office], which clearly isn't enough time to do it justice"?*

"*as it was...***the last time..***." = because of my past experience / the way things happened the last time I did the thing.