# A tricky "as it were" expression

Tags: phrase-usage

Even with reading [Meaning of “as it was” in context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114325/meaning-of-as-it-was-in-context) I am not sure I understand this in the following passage:

> Myers had as it were to re-create his personality before he became the wary
>   critic of evidence, the skillful handler of hypothesis, the learned neurologist and omnivorous reader of biological and cosmological matter, with
>   whom in later years we were acquainted.

Is this to only specify that Myers *indeed* re-created what he did or a is there a more complicated thing to it?

Answer (score 2):

Myers had to undergo a process that *resembled* re-creating his personality. The sense is 'it's impossible to describe exactly what he did, but this is the nearest I  (the writer) can come to it'.

Answer (score 2):

"As it were" in this case is synonymous with the phrase "in a manner of speaking", or "so to speak"

This implies that Myer's in a manner of speaking had to re-create himself to become the person you were later acquainted with.

Comment: Comparable to using scare quotes. "Myers had to 're-create his personality' before ...." Nowadays, the organic imagery would probably be considered such a familiar device that the scare quotes would be dropped.